# Add line break inside a function

Tags: javascript, date, time, line-breaks

I have got a problem with adding a line break inside my function. The function displays date and time. I need to display date on the fisrt line and time on the second. I have checked all the related answers. I have tried to use \n, br, join("\n"), tried to create br element inside my function, but unfortunately it did not work. Here is a piece of my code:

```
function getTime(a)
{ 
  var d;
  if(a) {
    d = new Date(a);
  } else {
    d = new Date();
  }
  return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'+
         ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + 
         (d.getYear() + 1900) + ' ' + // here instead of space I need to add a line break in order to display time on a new line 
         ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
         ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
         ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + '.' + 
         d.getMilliseconds();
}
```

Please, give me the hint how to solve the problem.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I assume you're displaying this on a web page. Is that right? If so you were right to use `<br>` and that works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/wxpz8njf/

Comment: you should tell us how this string is send to display, and in which environment or framework if there is some. I assume there is one, and that it sanitizes the string before display (`\n` or `<br>` should work, if not, they are most probably removed by somthing)

Comment: Instead of `d.getYear() + 1900` you should use `d.getFullYear()`. The two digit *getYear* was effectively introduced as deprecated in [*ECMA-262 ed 1*](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) in 1997. Why it hasn't been removed is a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a newline char:

```js
function getTime(a)
{ 
  var d;
  if(a) {
    d = new Date(a);
  } else {
    d = new Date();
  }
  return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'+
         ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + 
         (d.getYear() + 1900) + '\n' + // here instead of space I need to add a line break in order to display time on a new line 
         ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
         ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
         ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + '.' + 
         d.getMilliseconds();
}

console.log(getTime())
```

or if you want in markup inner html you add `<br>`

```js
    function getTime(a)
    { 
      var d;
      if(a) {
        d = new Date(a);
      } else {
        d = new Date();
      }
      return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.'+
             ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + 
             (d.getYear() + 1900) + ' <br> ' + // here instead of space I need to add a line break in order to display time on a new line 
             ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
             ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + 
             ('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + '.' + 
             d.getMilliseconds();
    }

document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML = getTime()
```

```html
<div class='test'></div>
```

if your dealing with html markup `<br>` tag is the correct way to display a carriage return.

Comment: `I have tried to use \n, br` <-- in original question

Comment: @Jamiec refresh with CTRL + F5 because this one should work.

Comment: @malutki5200 in a console it would. On a webpage it would not.

Comment: Yes, it does work fine, I never said it didn't. What I said was that you've just given a solution that the OP says s/he's already tried. See my comment on the question and thats the reason for my close vote.

Comment: Thanks a ton, one detail that I forgot to add is that I  use svgware library and use this code inside it, so maybe I need to change svgware code, but not the code inside my function

Comment: @SvetaMaltseva don't know about svgware, but adding `<br>` to a svg text node won't work, in this case you should probably try creating 2 text nodes; If you have problems open a new question with an example...